# Srollbars for a Flex4.5 Application in Application and Browser

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, browser, scrollbar

I'm googeling the whole evening. Either I'm blind or have no luck.

I'm developing a Application in Flash Builder 4.5 to control an server application, also not a classical Website. All is Spark and I set the minHeight and minWidth-Properties for the , because i have an Image and Navigators, and there becomes a strange effect, when the browserwindow is sliding smaller that the min-Properties.

The content and there scrollbars are already controlled over the parent containers, thats not the probelm.

Summary: What i expect from a upToDate-Application is:
When the Browserwindow is larger than the min-Properties, but too small for the content, the Application respectively the container should control the scroll bars.

If is the Browser-Window smaller than the min-Properties, i expecting scollbars from the browser. I think, in this case, the html-wrapper needs knowledge about the min-properties.

Can you give me a hint, what i can do, that i fit the expecting behavior?

Thanks a lot
Frank

Comment: I am honestly not sure what you're asking.  Is it possible to clarify?

Comment: What i want is a Browser Scrollbar, when the browser window is smaller that the minHeigt / minWidth Property of my <s:Application>-Application. When there should only appear, when the windows is smaller and disapear, when the window is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap your components in a scrollbar (VScrollBar seems adequate) or define your components as a scrollbar view port:

```
 <s:VScrollBar viewport="{myGroup}" height="100"/>
```

Comment: Zitat: "The content and there scrollbars are already controlled over the parent containers, thats not the probelm.". So i need no help with Scollers, but help with the Scrollbary controlled by browser

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the application can be seen in 3 levels:
HTML Wrapper > (Flash) Application > (Flash) Content

Is it what you want to achieve: If Application's size is bigger than HTML wrapper's (browser window size), use Browser's scroll bar; if Content's size is bigger than Application's size, use Application's scroll bar?

1. I didn't completely digest the Adobe's default html-template, but one thing for sure is that it disables the browser scrollbar. Building my own html-template is the way I chose. And by default, if the browser window cannot display content of a `div`, browser will automatically show the scroll bars.
2. To enable Application scroll bars while Content area is too large, just wrap the Content into a `Scroller`. Or you can put it into a `GroupBase` component with `clipAndEnableScrolling` property set to `true`, then explicitly define ScrollBar like user294702 suggested.

Comment: Hi Harry, that is exactly what I'm looking for. The second paragraph 1) is what I'm looking for. The paragraph 2) is done! Can you help me what is to be modified in the wrapper?

Comment: Hmm, I've just checked. The html-template that autohide part of Application is Flex 3. In Flex 4.5 thing is easier, just set `height` property of Application (not `minHeight`), then it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! only for my understanding, if I put the height, it does not mean that the swf always scale to that height. Thats not what i want. Can you give me al litte more information, where i have to set the height! That woulb be verry kindly. Thanks in advanced. Frank